# Oracle - Trouble creating a date reference table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm attempting to create a reference table, show all dates, and reference in my tables by the date key.  However, this is not working as I would expect.

```
DECLARE
  start_date DATE := TO_DATE('2009-01-01','YYYY-RR-DD');
  end_date DATE := TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-RR-DD');
BEGIN
  WHILE start_date < end_date LOOP
      SELECT 
            TO_CHAR(start_date, '-YYYYMMDD') AS DATE_KEY
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "ACTUAL_DATE"
          , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) AS "YEAR"
          , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS "MONTH"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'MONTH') AS "MONTH_NAME"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'WW') AS "WEEK_OF_YEAR"
          , EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_date) AS "DAY"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DDD') AS "DAY_OF_YEAR"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DAY') AS "WEEKDAY"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'Q') AS "QTR_OF_YEAR"
          , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'MONTH DD, YYYY') AS FRIENDLY
      INTO V_DATE
      FROM dual;
      start_date := start_date+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm getting this error, but no matter what I try, I keep getting errors.
I've tried declaring V_DATE, but that hasn't worked properly.

As a work-around, I was able to create the required table in Excel, but it has a minor issue with the
week of year. I can fix that with a update query after loading this data.
It would be ideal to have an actual query that will populate, since this data will likely live beyond the additional years I listed.

Thank you, Allan

Comment: You have a wrong format mask in date conversion. You should use 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: You're getting *what* error? Your declaration format masks have RR instead of MM; you might want to use ANSI date literals for those. You can also populate you table with a hierarchical query and avoid PL/SQL.

Comment: You are using Oracle built-in functions.  Why do you need a table?

Comment: I assume V_DATE will end up being a view? Why do you need PL/SQL code to populate it? You can do it all in plain SQL.

Comment: Extending a current design. This table is referenced in a data warehouse setup. I need to extend the date but there was no existing code for how it was originally created.

Comment: "I've tried declaring V_DATE" - your code refers to a record variable called v_date, so yes you have to declare it. Although as @GordonLinoff mentions, you probably meant `insert into ... select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the table with one statement as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE refdates AS 
  SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(start_date, '-YYYYMMDD') AS DATE_KEY
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "ACTUAL_DATE"
      , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) AS "YEAR"
      , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS "MONTH"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'MONTH') AS "MONTH_NAME"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'WW') AS "WEEK_OF_YEAR"
      , EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_date) AS "DAY"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DDD') AS "DAY_OF_YEAR"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DAY') AS "WEEKDAY"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'Q') AS "QTR_OF_YEAR"
      , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'MONTH DD, YYYY') AS FRIENDLY
  FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('2008-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') + level as start_date
        FROM   dual
        CONNECT BY level < 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax:

```
select . . .
into v_date
. . .
```

is used (in Oracle) to select into a variable.

You seem to want to insert rows in a table:

```
insert into ??( . . . )
    <your select here>;
```

The `??` is your table name.  The `. . .` is the list of columns.

Also, you *could* dispense with the PL/SQL and do this all in a single query, by using a CTE to generate all the dates (either using `connect by` or a recursive CTE).